# Is Concurrent cudaMemcpyAsync possible?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm writing some test code to get familiar with the concurrent attributes of `cudaMemcpyAsync`.

When I was trying to do concurrent `cudaMemcpyAsync` in a **single context**, the copy operations are queuing up and get executed one by one with throughput `12.4 GB/s`, which is consistent with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893479/cudamemcpyasync-and-streams-behaviour-understanding):
[image]

But when I tried to do concurrent `cudaMemcpyAsync` in **different contexts** (by separating them into 4 processes), it seems that the first and the last one are running concurrently:[image]

The first 2 sequential `cudaMemcpyAsync` are running with a throughput `12.4 GB/s` while the last 2 concurrent ones are running with a throughput `5.3 GB/s`.

How can I do concurrent `cudaMemcpyAsync` within single context?

I'm using `CUDA9.0` on `TITAN Xp`, which has 2 copy engines.

**EDIT**:

Code for scenario 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

inline
cudaError_t checkCuda(cudaError_t result)
{
  if (result != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "CUDA Runtime Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(result));
    assert(result == cudaSuccess);
  }
  return result;
}

const int nStreams = 8;
const int N = 100000000;
const int bytes = N * sizeof(int);
int* arr_H;
int* arr_D[nStreams];
cudaStream_t stream[nStreams];
int args[nStreams];
pthread_t threads[nStreams];

void* worker(void *arg)
{
  int i = *((int *)arg);
  checkCuda(cudaMemcpyAsync(arr_D[i], arr_H, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream[i]));

  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < nStreams; i++)
    checkCuda(cudaStreamCreate(&stream[i]));

  checkCuda(cudaMallocHost((void**)&arr_H, bytes));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    arr_H[i] = random();

  for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; i++)
    checkCuda(cudaMalloc((void**)&arr_D[i], bytes));

  for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; i++) {
    args[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, &args[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; i++)
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

  cudaFreeHost(arr_H);
  for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; i++) {
    checkCuda(cudaStreamDestroy(stream[i]));
    cudaFree(arr_D[i]);
  }

  return 0;
```

Code for scenario 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

inline
cudaError_t checkCuda(cudaError_t result)
{
  if (result != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "CUDA Runtime Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(result));
    assert(result == cudaSuccess);
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  const int nStreams = 1;
  const int N = 100000000;
  const int bytes = N * sizeof(int);
  int* arr_H;
  int* arr_D[nStreams];
  cudaStream_t stream[nStreams];

  for(int i = 0; i < nStreams; i++)
    checkCuda(cudaStreamCreate(&stream[i]));

  checkCuda(cudaMallocHost((void**)&arr_H, bytes));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    arr_H[i] = random();

  for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; i++)
    checkCuda(cudaMalloc((void**)&arr_D[i], bytes));

  for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; i++)
    checkCuda(cudaMemcpyAsync(arr_D[i], arr_H, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream[i]));

  cudaFreeHost(arr_H);
  for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; i++) {
    checkCuda(cudaStreamDestroy(stream[i]));
    cudaFree(arr_D[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Code 2 is basically copied from Code 1. I used a python script to run multiple processes concurrently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

N = 4

processes = [subprocess.Popen('./a.out', shell=True) for _ in range(N)]

for process in processes:
    process.wait()
```

Comment: I think you can do this using different streams for each copy call withing a context.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing in the first scenario, where I did 4 copy calls for 4 streams respectively.

Comment: I assume you are using pinned memory right? Can you show the code?

Comment: I've updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: The code seems fine to me, maybe I am wrong and you can not do concurrent copies to the same device in the same context. Simply out of curiosity, why would you do this? it will take the same time to put them one after the other and to do them concurrently.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'm writing a concurrent, single context CUDA program where there're memcpys for both large chunks and really small chunks. The small chunks may get delayed if the larger one get transferred first. Any ideas on this?

Comment: In my applications I just make sure that the small ones are transferred first. An alternative would be to split the big one into multiple memcpy calls and make sure you transfer small ones in-between if needed earlier. Clearly your attempted solution is better if it works.

Comment: It could be, that the system decides it won't matter to do them concurrently or not, so it just does it someway. If you try accessing data submitted by a later stream before data from an earlier stream, it might trigger that to copy over earlier

Comment: Thanks Ander for your inspiring suggestion! Thanks Daniel but I'm not clear about  'accessing data submitted by a later stream'. I made memcpy calls at the same time.

Comment: I mean to just reverse the order in which you read them in respect to the order you copied them

Comment: Like memcpy 1...2...3...4 then streamSync 4...3...2...1